# How to get an off-screen plain surface from 'normal' IDirect3D9Surface

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d9, ms-media-foundation

I'm working on a media player with Media Foundation. I'm trying to use post processing with DXVA-HD. However, when I try to do a VideoProcessBltHD using the HD device, it fails with E_INVALIDARGS. What I doubt is it is not somehow working correctly with the ID39Surface I'm providing as input. I'm getting the input surface from 'IMFMediaBuffer' (which I get from reading a sample from the SourceReader).

I'm extracting the surface as follows:
CHECK_HR (hr = MFGetService( video_buffer, MR_BUFFER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IDirect3DSurface9), (void**)&pSurface) );

However, in the [DXVA-HD example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the VideoProcessBltHD works fine.

Whereas the IDirect3DSurface9 surface in the sample code is an off screen plain surface.
How do I pass 'my surface'(which has the video data) as an off screen plain surface to the video processor and the get 'blt-operation' succeed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mots

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing full DirectX SDK, switch runtime library to debug mode in DirectX Control Pannel, turn full validation, break on error and run your app in debug mode. This way, you will get DirectX human readable error description.

Comment: I'm getting E_INVALIDARG as the error. The documentation says,  VideoProcessBltHD returns this error if it doesn't find the input arguments to be incorrect. I've narrowed it down to my input surface being invalid for this function. The only difference I see with the sample source code provided on MSDN is that MSDN uses an off-screen plain surface and I don't know how to get that from the surface I have. Also, on integrating the sample code in my code and giving the new surface (the off screen plain surface), the blt works fine. Any clues on getting an off-screen surface? Thanks

Comment: @mots_g, Invalid Arg is a generalized error, it doesnt tell anything usefull. Debug mode runtime explains in human language what is in particular wrong with invalid argument. It could be - wrong surface dimensions, wrong memory pool, wrong surface format, etc,. etc.,

Comment: I tried debugging as you suggested. The code did not break, but it started printing VideoProcessBlt failed with error 0x%x.-2147084809. On checking DirectX Error lookup, -2147024809 = E_INVALIDARG.

Comment: @mots_g So, you opened DirectX control pannel, turned direct3d to using debug runtime, break on error, full validation and running from visual c++ enviroment Run from Debug, still gives you this short info? Something is still wrong. Try this link: http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/direct3d-programming-tip-5-use-the-debug-runtime/

Comment: Yes, I had followed all the steps. On checking the link above, I found my debug output level was on Less. I changed it to More. However, I'm still getting the same output as before. In my output console, I'm also getting the following at the beginning of code execution:  Direct3D9: (ERROR) :ASSERTION FAILED! File s:\gfx_aug09\windows\directx\dxg\inactive\d3d9\d3d\fw\lhbatchfilter.cpp Line 3466: pArgs->Flags.Discard

Comment: @mots_g Ok, lets get to the direct3d function itself. As I understand, VideoProcessBlt expects a surface, created as a rendertarget to be filled by the call to this function. I suspect using MFGetService returns a buffer, but its not a surface you expect, but again, I dont know how do you perform presentation of data... Try creating a new, appropriate size, desktop format, render target surface and pass this to VideoProcessBlt to get trough